# C++ Create a job container that you can add functions too, that will start in a thread, and then be removed once it is done

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, c++17

I want to create a container that I can push functions into, that will instantly be started in a thread. Once the function is complete, it should automatically be removed from the container so that the container does not grow indefinitely.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class j_thread {
    std::thread thread;
public:

    j_thread() {}

    template<typename F>
    j_thread(const F& f) : thread(f) {}

    j_thread& operator = (j_thread&& other) {
        this->thread.swap(other.thread);
        return *this;
    }

    virtual ~j_thread() {
        thread.join();
    }
};

class jobs {

    std::map<size_t, j_thread> threads;

public:

    template<typename F>
    void add_job(const F &function) {

        size_t job_id = threads.size();

        auto wrapped_function = [&function, job_id, this]() {
            function();
            threads.erase(job_id);
        };

        threads[job_id] = j_thread(wrapped_function);
    }

    void wait_for_all() {
        while(threads.size() != 0) {}
    }
};


int main() {

    jobs j;
    j.add_job([](){std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;});
    j.add_job([](){std::cout << "world" << std::endl;});
    j.wait_for_all();
}
```

But when run gives the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Invalid argument
hello
terminate called recursively
12:15:44: The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `join` within the body of thread is undefined behaviour.

Look at error conditions for [join](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join):

> Error Conditions resource_deadlock_would_occur if this->get_id() ==
>   std::this_thread::get_id() (deadlock detected)

Your body is:

```
    auto wrapped_function = [&function, job_id, this]() {
        function();
        threads.erase(job_id);
    };
```

where you call `erase`, dtor of `jthread` is being called which calls `join` on joinable thread.

Instead of `join`, in dtor you should call `detach`.

To avoid dangling reference `function` must be captured by value.

Also you have to add some mutex to avoid data race on map, when calling `size` and `erase`:

```
std::mutex m;

int size() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{m};
    return threads.size();
}

auto wrapped_function = [f = function, job_id, this]() {
    f();
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m);
    threads.erase(job_id);
};

void wait_for_all() {
    while(size() != 0) {}
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/578de402ae93f04c)